# django celery - running two queues in a single worker

Tags: django, celery

I am using celery for my project requirements.
Currently i have created a queue 'HighPriorityQueue' along with the default queue , i.e there
will be a single worker and two queues.

There will be different tasks getting queued to both these queues. I need to process the 
'HighPriorityQueue' whenever a task gets queued in it.

My doubt is that how will celery process this queues? Will celery process the queues parallel?
Or can i make it in such a way that , if some task is queued in the 'HighPriorityQueue' it should be processed immediately , irrespective of the jobs that are already been queued in the
default one?

Please advice and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*Whoa, old question...*

Celery isn't able to place priority on a set of queues. Your best option is to have a high-priority worker pool that only consumes the `HighPriortyQueue` and a default worker pool that consumes either `default`+`HighPriorityQueue` or just `default.

Some message brokers ([RabbitMQ for sure](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html)) allow you to set priority within the queue, basically pushing important messages into the queue at the top to be consumed first, then your one Celery worker could dumbly consume those messages and accomplish basically what you want. Doing this at the queue level comes with it's own challenges/gotchas though.